# How to encode latitude and longitude in one value in geodash2 (Python)?

Tags: python, encode

I am trying to encode latitude and longitude like this:

```
location_start = geohash2.encode(lat_start,lon_start, g)
```

and get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I have no idea is is something wrong with my values, the format they are in or geodash2.

where should I use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()?

Answer (score 1):

This error means that you are trying to pass in lat_start or lon_start or g not a float value but a Series of values. Please check your lat_start, lon_start and g.

For  example:
        [image]

You can zip two Series at iterate them:
[image]

Comment: yes I am trying to encode series, but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: As I know you cannot put Series into this method. You need to iterate through the series

Comment: I have added how you can do it in the answer, last picture.